# How to get min value at max date in sql?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with snapshot data. It has productid and date and quantity columns. I need to find min value in the max date. Let's say, we have product X: X had the last snapshot at Y date but it has two snapshots at Y with 9 and 8 quantity values. I need to get

```
product_id | date | quantity
     X        Y       8
```

So far I came up with this.

```
select 
  productid
  , max(snapshot_date) max_date
  , min(quantity) min_quantity
from snapshot_table
group by 1
```

It works but I don't know why. Why this does not bring min value for each date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `RANK` here along with a scalar subquery:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY quantity) rnk
    FROM snapshot_table
    WHERE snapshot_date = (SELECT MAX(snapshot_date) FROM snapshot_table)
)

SELECT productid, snapshot_date, quantity
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Note that this solution caters to the possibility that two or more records happened to be tied for having the lower quantity among those most recent records.

**Edit:** We could simplify by doing away with the CTE and instead using the `QUALIFY` clause for the restriction on the `RANK`:

```sql
SELECT productid, snapshot_date, quantity
FROM snapshot_table
WHERE snapshot_date = (SELECT MAX(snapshot_date) FROM snapshot_table)
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY quantity) = 1;
```

Comment: As a consideration to this and other answers that utilize a CTE, consider including a `QUALIFY` clause.  Documentation for that can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause

Comment: @DanielZagales Nice suggestion.  Most databases don't have `QUALIFY` (BigQuery and Teradata being two exceptions).  I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider also below approach

```
select distinct product_id, 
  max(snapshot_date) over product as max_date,
  first_value(quantity) over(product order by snapshot_date desc, quantity) as min_quantity
from your_table
window product as (partition by product_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

use row_number()

```
  with cte as (select *, 
  row_number() over(partition by product_id order by date desc) rn 
 from table_name) select * from cte where rn=1
```